# Math Generator pop quiz

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple multiple choice Math question game, so far I did manage to  randomize the question and the answer, but sometimes when ever I click on the Correct answer it is saying it is Incorrect("Debug.log"), it actually moves on to the next question sometimes when I click on the wrong answer. I am using boolean to determine which answer is correct. When I first click the UI start button, all of the options log "Correct" and "Not Correct", instead of just one answer.  I know it has something to do with my logic, but not sure where I messed up.

**Code**

```
public class MathGen : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameObject Question;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Button button;
    int a;
    int b;
    int Score;
    int Answer;
    int Fake1;
    int Fake2;
    int Fake3;
    int Fake4;
    bool Option1;
    bool Option2;
    bool Option3;
    bool Option4;
    public GameObject OptionA;
    public GameObject OptionB;
    public GameObject OptionC;
    public GameObject OptionD;

    List<GameObject> optionsList = new List<GameObject>();
    GameObject choosedOption;
    void Awake()
    {
        optionsList.Add(OptionA);
        optionsList.Add(OptionB);
        optionsList.Add(OptionC);
        optionsList.Add(OptionD);
    }

    public void UserStart() // this is called through a UI Button
    {
        Score = 0;
        a = Random.Range(0, 10);
        b = Random.Range(0, 10);
        choosedOption = optionsList[Random.Range(0, optionsList.Count)];
        UDebug.Log(choosedOption.name);
        UDebug.Log(Option1 + " A");
        UDebug.Log(Option2 + " B");
        UDebug.Log(Option3 + " C");
        UDebug.Log(Option4 + " D");
    }

    public void Next()
    {
        if (Option1 || Option2 || Option3 || Option4 == true)
        {
            UDebug.Log("Correct");
            a = Random.Range(0, 10);
            b = Random.Range(0, 10);
            choosedOption = optionsList[Random.Range(0, optionsList.Count)];
        }
        if (Option1 || Option2 || Option3 || Option4 == false)
        {
            UDebug.Log("Not Correct");
            button.onClick.Invoke();
        }
        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Question.GetComponent<Text>().text = a + " + " + b;
        Answer = a + b;
        Fake1 = a + b + 5;
        Fake2 = a + b + 1;
        Fake3 = a + b + 3;
        Fake4 = a + b + 10;


       // None of these give me True when I clicked on the button for the first time

        if (choosedOption == OptionA)
        {
            OptionA.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Answer.ToString();
            Option1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OptionA.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Fake1.ToString();
            Option1 = false;
        }

        if (choosedOption == OptionB)
        {
            OptionB.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Answer.ToString();
            Option2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OptionB.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Fake2.ToString();
            Option2 = false;
        }

        if (choosedOption == OptionC)
        {
            OptionC.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Answer.ToString();
            Option3 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OptionC.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Fake3.ToString();
            Option3 = false;
        }

        if (choosedOption == OptionD)
        {
            OptionD.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Answer.ToString();
            Option4 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OptionD.GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Fake4.ToString();
            Option4 = false;
        }

    }

    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements are not correct.

```
 if (Option1 || Option2 || Option3 || Option4 == true)
 {
    UDebug.Log("Correct");
    a = Random.Range(0, 10);
    b = Random.Range(0, 10);
    choosedOption = optionsList[Random.Range(0, optionsList.Count)];
 }
 if (Option1 || Option2 || Option3 || Option4 == false)
 {
    UDebug.Log("Not Correct");
    button.onClick.Invoke();
 }
```

The first `if` statement will show "Correct" if *any* of the four buttons has the correct answer; regardless of which one the player clicked.  One of the buttons will *always* have the correct answer.  This is why your the log always says "Correct", no matter what answer you click.

The second `if` statement will say "Not Correct" if any of the first three buttons had the correct answer, or if the fourth button had the incorrect answer.  Again, it doesn't matter which button you actually clicked.

I don't see anywhere in your code where you're checking which button the player clicks.  You're looking at all four of your buttons each time the player clicks one button.  You need to determine which button the player clicked, and then check whether that button had the correct or incorrect answer.

On a separate topic, the `Update` method is meant for code which needs to run constantly, such as moving a character or updating a timer.  The code that you have in `Update` only needs to run once per question.  You should put that code somewhere where it'll only run once per question, rather than in `Update` where it'll run dozens of times per second.

Comment: oh wow, what am I thinking, let me try changing it up a bit. thx @Ben Rubin

Comment: Ik, but when ever I try another method its not as effective as update, I tried to put it on a UI button, but it is not updated sometimes, its like a delay, it gives the answer from the last question and not the current question, its weird.

Comment: Buttons should work instantaneously.  If you're getting a delay, that sounds like something else is wrong.  If you're calling `Next` with those same `if` statements from your button handler, that's probably why it seemed like you were getting results from the last question.

Comment: yes it could actually be that, let me change around my code, and I will keep you updated when done.

Comment: when I click the start button, all of the options are false automatically, would you happen to know why? one of the answers are supposed to be = true.

Comment: only when I click the Button for a second time, one of the answers becomes true.

Comment: I'd have to see the code that you're using behind your button handler.

Comment: the public void UserStart() - is the button , this is called upon through the user interface.

Comment: You should be calling all that code in `Update` once and only once in `UserStart`.  So you should put that code into `UserStart` or put it into a method that is called from `UserStart`.